# androidx.lifecycle.Transformations not imported

Tags: androidx, lifecycle

What's the new way of writing androidx.lifecycle.Transformations?

I'm following this on Kotlin course

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

already added dependency "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1
but it is not found